# Proper Bracha on Chanuka candles

Tags: chanuka, halacha, blessing, minhag

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Lhadlik ner (SHEL) Chanukah](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12631/lhadlik-ner-shel-chanukah)

What is the proper Nusach - Lehadlik Ner *Shel* Chanuka or LeHadlik Ner Chanuka?