# Different customs regarding the blessing before lighting the menorah

Tags: minhag, grammar-dikduk, chanuka, nuschaot

There are varying customs as to the text of the bracha we recite before lighting the menorah.

Ashkenazim generally end the blessing with the words:

> .לְהַדְלִיק נֵר שֶׁל חֲנֻכָּה

However, Hasidim (at least in the far eastern dynasties such as Lubavitch, Breslov, and Skver, I don't really know about the other dynasties) generally end the blessing differently, reciting

> .לְהַדְלִיק נֵר חֲנֻכָּה

instead of the aforementioned ending, I have heard that this was the custom of the Arizal.

I have several questions concerning the above:

- What is the grammatical difference between the two versions? Both seem to (in my mind) translate out to "to kindle the Chanukah lights".
- Where does the school of the Arizal write that it was his custom to recite להדליק נר חנכה, omitting the של from the traditional Ashkenazi rendering? What is the reason for this?
- I would assume that if it was the Arizal's custom to end the blessing להדליק נר חנכה, Sephardim would also render the blessing that way, since they generally follow the Arizal for nusach. How do Sephardim conclude the blessing?
- Scholars generally agree that the customs of the Yemenite Jewry seem to be most ancient. How to the Yemenites conclude the blessing?

Finally,

- Is there a place in the Gemara or other early Rabbinic work (such as Rambam) which outlines the text for the blessing, and which text does it follow?

I apologize for the many questions but they seem to me all related; if this question is asking too many sub questions I'd be more than happy to split them up into separate questions.

Comment: There's also להדליק נר שלחנוכה

Comment: The blessings are in the Talmud Shabbat 23a, but without checking for manuscript variants there's little value in checking what happens to be printed in the common Vilna edition. Almost certainly every variant will be attested to, since anyone "composing" a Nusach would know to check there.

Comment: I realize you have more questions here than the linked dupe, so if/when you edit to remove those parts and hopefully reference the other post, we can certainly reopen. This is just a temporary hold for you to reconfigure your thoughts and post

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm sorry, but I don't see how the question you linked and duped of this one answers any of my above questions. Could you point out to me how it does?

Comment: At the very least we have "What is the reason for this?" But anyway don't you think your question will better get what you want if you incorporate what you've learned from there? Like about the third option שלחנכה, and the Shulchan Arukh taking the same position as you ascribe to the Arizal as regards the Sephardic practice? Editing is free, remember

Comment: @ezra I added an answer for you on the duplicated question FYI, see https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/87577/11501

Comment: @d If MY's rule for duplicates really also prohibits questions that partially overlap, the flag label needs to be changed from "This question was marked as an *exact* duplicate of an existing question."

Comment: @mbloch Thanks. I've upvoted your answer over there. I'm thinking about deleting this post.